# how to upload more than 1mb file using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am stuck with file uploading. I am trying to upload a file which is more than 1mb even after setting maximum size in php.ini and htaccess but still I get an error message saying ''File size should be less than 1mb''

How can maximum file size be set?

In php.ini file, I updated to this:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '125M');  
ini_set('post_max_size', '125M');
```

In .htaccess, I did this:

```
 php_value memory_limit 125M
 php_value post_max_size 128M
 php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
```

This is my controller

```
public function handle_upload($str,$is_required)
    {

        $image_validate = $this->config->item('file_validate');

        if (isset($_FILES["file"]) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

            $file_type         = $_FILES["file"]['type'];
            $file_size         = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
            $file_name         = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $allowed_extension = $image_validate['allowed_extension'];
            $ext               = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $allowed_mime_type = $image_validate['allowed_mime_type'];

            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $mtype = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            finfo_close($finfo);

            if (!in_array($mtype, $allowed_mime_type)) {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', 'File Type Not Allowed');
                return false;
            }

            if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_extension) || !in_array($file_type, $allowed_mime_type)) {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', 'Extension Not Allowed');
                return false;
            }

            if ($file_size > $image_validate['upload_size']) {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', $this->lang->line('file_size_shoud_be_less_than') . number_format($image_validate['upload_size'] / 1048576, 2) . " MB");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } else {
          if($is_required==0){
             $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', 'Please choose a file to upload.');
            return false;
          }else{
             return true;
          }

        }
```

Comment: Specifically the part where you need to restart the server for the changes to take place.

Comment: first of all, does your script work with files < 1MB? 2nd, is this for a shared hosting with upload limits?